# How to refresh div data in every second automatically in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I going crazy, I have this code in cakephp table:

```
<td style="width:50%">
    <div id="progress<?=$turnTime['TurnTime']['name'];?>">
        <?php if ($turnTime['TurnTime']['end_time'] < date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
                echo __('Waiting...');
            }else{
                $percent = ((strtotime($turnTime['TurnTime']['end_time']) - strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))/
                (strtotime($turnTime['TurnTime']['end_time']) - strtotime($turnTime['TurnTime']['start_time'])))*100;
                $p = 'width: '.round($percent, 2).'%';
                //show the time left
                $current_date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $since_current = $current_date->diff(new DateTime($turnTime['TurnTime']['end_time']));

                echo $since_current->h.' hours - '.$since_current->i.' minutes - '.$since_current->s.' seconds Left';
        ?>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active" id="bar">
            <div class="bar" style= "<?php echo $p; ?>"></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>  
</td>
```

I want to refresh the div data automatically in every second for

```
<div id="progress<?=$turnTime['TurnTime']['name'];?>">
```

I tried several ways, but.... Please help me, thanks

I tried using jQuery like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(showText(), 1000);
        function showText(){
            //alert("11");
            $("#progress<?=$turnTime['TurnTime']['name'];?>").html(....some codes here...);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

But it does not work...

Comment: You've used an AJAX label for this question, so I'd suggest using AJAX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showText()
    {
        var hidden_field = $('#progress_get_me').val();
        $("#progress"+hidden_field).html(....some codes here...);
    }

    $(function()
    {
        setInterval(showText, 1000);
    });

</script>


<input type="hidden" value="<?=$turnTime['TurnTime']['name'];?>" id="progress_get_me" />
```

**Explanation**

Programmer created function must be declared out side of `$(document).ready` so i corrected you there.

second don't use `php` inside `jQuery` it's not good idea and from personal experience it's doesn't work often i don't know reason.

Third use hidden field when ever you want to use `php` inside `jQuery` also you can use ajax call to server and then from response object use those value inside `jQuery`.

Comment: -1 this contains the same error with the `setInterval` call as the question

Comment: @AD7six what do you mean..??? i have tested and there's no error...please check before -1...thanx for vote...

Comment: Compare http://jsfiddle.net/AmjXW/ to http://jsfiddle.net/XUBta/ , and see my answer ;)

Comment: @AD7six i don't know what is wrong with my answer..?? i have already tested it cross browser... can u pls let me know so i can correct myself..???

Comment: also "Programmer created function must be declared out side" not true. "Third use hidden field when ever you want to use" this seems like advise based on a similar misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

### The setInterval call is wrong

In the question there's this:

> setInterval(showText(), 1000);

Which will call *the result of* `showText` every second, however `showText` has no return value (much less, returning a function) so it'll effectively call `showText` only once on document ready.

To fix this error use:

```
setInterval(showText, 1000);
```

Which will call *the function* `showText` once a second.